# Como tornar uma ListView "Clicável"?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, onclick

Tenho um sistema simples de agenda telefônica, onde há `Activity`s para:

- Cadastro;
- Edição do cadastro;
- Remoção do cadastro;
- E uma última para ver todos os contatos dentro de uma `ListView`.

Todos os registros vem de uma tabela no banco de dados. Gostaria de saber como faço para acessar cada registro quando tocar em uma linha de registro na lista.

```
package com.br.projetoeducadastro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Contatos extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private CursorAdapter dataSource;

    private static final String campos[] = {"_id", "nome", "telefone"};

    ListView list;
    SQLiteHelper helper;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Contatos.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    TextView tvNome, tvId, tvTelefone;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contatos);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        helper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.query("clientes", campos, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c, campos,
                    new int[]{R.id.tvId, R.id.tvNome, R.id.tvTelefone});
            list.setAdapter(dataSource);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nenhum Registro Encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Contatos.this, Index.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa criar um `Listener`.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295226/how-to-create-listview-onitemclicklistener

Comment: Olá Lucas Moresco, obrigado pela ajuda, mas não entendo o motivo do erro na minha list nessa passagem:    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Log.d("##","Items " + list[arg2] );
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar um listener, desta forma:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.d("##","Items " +  list[arg2] );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Lucas Moresco, obrigado pela ajuda, mas meu "list[arg2]" está dando erro, poderia me explicar?

Comment: Já consegui resolver, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo que você trabalhe com múltiplos fragments em uma activity, ao invés de múltiplas activity. Estes códigos funcionarão dentro de um fragment, em uma activity vai precisar de algumas modificações.

Adicione esta linha no OnCreateView():

```
list.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getActivity);
```

Adicione estas linhas:

```
private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

        public ListAdapter(Context c) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return c.getCount(); //
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null ){

                convertView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.linha_listview, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.TextView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                viewHolder.TextView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);                    

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("onClick - position",     String.valueOf(position));
                        Fragment registro = new VerRegistro();                            

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                        bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(position));

                        registro.setArguments(bundle);
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, registro);
                        ft.addToBackStack(null);
                        ft.commit();

                    }
                });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }        
            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView TextView1;
            TextView TextView2;
        }
    }
```

Note que a linha da listview terá um layout próprio. Ao clicar o fragment VerRegistro será chamado.